# Generate string with special characters and all combinations

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all possible combinations of given strings with special chars after each char in the string.

Given:

```
const messages = generateMessages(['Test'], ['.', ','], 3);
```

What i have done so far:

```
function generateMessages(messages, specialChars, depth) {
    const generatedMessages = [];
    messages.forEach((message) => {
        for(let x = 0; x < message.length; x++) {
            specialChars.forEach((specialChar) => {
                let currentDepth = 1;
                while(currentDepth <= depth) {
                    let temp = '';
                    temp += message.substring(0, x+1); // I think here is the problem!
                    temp += generateSpecialChars(specialChar, currentDepth);
                    temp += message.substring(x +1);
                    generatedMessages.push(temp);
                    currentDepth++;
                }
            })
        }
    })

    return generatedMessages;
}

function generateSpecialChars(char, depth) {
    let temp = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        temp += char;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Current output:

```
[
  'T.est', 'T..est', 'T...est',
  'T,est', 'T,,est', 'T,,,est',
  'Te.st', 'Te..st', 'Te...st',
  'Te,st', 'Te,,st', 'Te,,,st',
  'Tes.t', 'Tes..t', 'Tes...t',
  'Tes,t', 'Tes,,t', 'Tes,,,t',
  'Test.', 'Test..', 'Test...',
  'Test,', 'Test,,', 'Test,,,'
]
```

**The output i want:**

```
[
  'T.est', 'T..est', 'T...est',
  'Te.st', 'T.e.st', 'T..e.st', T...e.st',
  'Te..st', 'T.e..st', 'T..e..st', T...e..st',
  'Te...st', 'T.e..st', 'T..e...st', T...e...st',
  'Tes.t', 'T.es.t', 'T..es.t', T...es.t',
  'Te.s.t', 'T.e.s.t', 'T..e.s.t', T...e.s.t',
  ...
]
```

I also want to combine the special chars dependend on the depth:
Assume the depth is 3 and we have the special chars [',' and '.']

```
[
  'T.est', 'T..est', 'T...est',
  'T.est', 'T..est', 'T..,est',
  'T.est', 'T..est', 'T.,,est',
  'T.est', 'T..est', 'T,,,est',
  'T.est', 'T.,est', 'T,,,est',
  'T.est', 'T,,est', 'T,,,est',
  'T,est', 'T,,est', 'T,,,est',
  ...
]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why aren't there any commas in "the output I want"?

Comment: is `'T,e.st'` a possible output?

Comment: Please note that, as the number of characters in the two strings grows, the number of output strings grows geometrically.  You can get to very large result sets very quickly.

Comment: Barmer: There should also be commas. I just simplified the output and added some combinations below.
Mark Schultheiss: Yes like all combinations should be possible.
Tim Roberts: Yes thank you for mention that. The solution of Victor L. produce exactly what i want. But with multiple messages or increasing the depth or the amount of chars in the message it is not possible to save it (out of memory), or it's very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate all possible combinations of strings with special characters, you can use a two-step approach:

- You need to write a function that can create all the different ways
  to combine the special characters with a given number of times. For
  example, if you have two special characters, "," and ".", and you
  want to combine them three times, you can get these combinations:
  ",,,", ",,.", ",.,", ",..", ".,,", ".,.", "..,", "...".
- You need to write another function that can insert these combinations of special characters after each character in the string. For
  example, if you have the string "Test" and the combination "..,", you can insert it after each character and get "T..,est", "Te..,st",
  "Tes..,t", "Test..,".

> But there is a problem with this code. It does not make all the
> possible ways to mix the letters and the special characters. It misses
> some ways like "T.est". The problem is that the second function does
> not try to put nothing after a letter in the word. It only tries to
> put one or more special characters, up to a certain limit. To fix
> this, you need to change the second function a little bit. You need to
> add another way to call the function again, without putting any
> special character after the letter.

For example:

```js
function generateSpecialChars(specialChars, length) {
  if (length === 0) {
    return [""];
  }
  if (length === 1) {
    return specialChars;
  }
  const combinations = [];
  specialChars.forEach((specialChar) => {
    const subCombinations = generateSpecialChars(specialChars, length - 1);
    subCombinations.forEach((subCombination) => {
      combinations.push(subCombination + specialChar);
    });
  });
  return combinations;
}

function generateMessages(messages, specialChars, depth) {
  const generatedMessages = [];
  messages.forEach((message) => {
    generateHelper(message, 0, "", specialChars, depth, generatedMessages);
  });
  return generatedMessages;
}

function generateHelper(message, index, prefix, specialChars, depth, output) {
  if (index >= message.length) {
    output.push(prefix);
    return;
  }
  const char = message[index];
  generateHelper(
    message,
    index + 1,
    prefix + char,
    specialChars,
    depth,
    output
  );
  let repeat = 1;
  while (repeat <= depth) {
    const repeatedChars = generateSpecialChars(specialChars, repeat);
    repeatedChars.forEach((repeatedChar) => {
      generateHelper(
        message,
        index + 1,
        prefix + char + repeatedChar,
        specialChars,
        depth,
        output
      );
    });
    repeat++;
  }
}

const messages = generateMessages(["Test"], [".", ","], 3);
console.log(messages)
```

Comment: your result appears to be missing things like `'T.est', 'Tes.t'`

Comment: Thank you for your indication. I updated my answer. - @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: Thanks @Victor L., thats exactly what i wanted to get as result.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it works fine for you.